# Hibernate error when creating session

Tags: java, hibernate

When I try to get hibernate session `(Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();)` I get an error like:

```
Testcase: testMain(test.smssender.SmsSenderTest):        Caused an ERROR
null
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
        at org.hibernate.engine.UnsavedValueFactory.instantiate(UnsavedValueFactory.java:22)
        at org.hibernate.engine.UnsavedValueFactory.getUnsavedIdentifierValue(UnsavedValueFactory.java:44)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildIdentifierProperty(PropertyFactory.java:44)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.(EntityMetamodel.java:123)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.(AbstractEntityPersister.java:434)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:55)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:226)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1294)
        at vas.framework.hibernate.HibernateUtil.(HibernateUtil.java:38)
```

The content of HibernateUtil.java file is here: http://pastebin.com/exCCdX2P

I couldnt locate the problem. Any help?

UPDATE: Recreating Entity objects solved my problem.

Comment: Make sure that the required jar files are included for hibernate

Comment: The stacktrace suggests that the Entity class could not be instantiated.  Could one of your entity class constructor(s) throw an exception or maybe you haven't got a default constructor in all of them?

Comment: publish the code for the entity you are trying to save.

Comment: Recreating Entity objects solved my problem. Thanks for helps.

Comment: ASAP, please answer the question yourself and accept it. Nice work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recreating Entity objects solved my problem.